# Remove product image when deleting product WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm deleting all of my out of stock products automatically with an sql statement (I saw the example at another question here on StackOverFlow).
This deletes the product from the database but leaves the image in the media library.
Is there a way to delete the image aswell?

Code:

```
function remove_out_of_stock_status(){   
   global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    DELETE p FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p 
    join {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm 
    on p.ID = pm.post_id 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product' 
    and pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' 
    and pm.meta_value = 'outofstock'
" );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'remove_out_of_stock_status', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`before_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/before_delete_post/) hook to delete product image, If product get permanently deleted.

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_thumbnail_before_delete_post');
function delete_thumbnail_before_delete_post($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post->post_type === 'product') {
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        if ($thumb_id) {
            wp_delete_attachment($thumb_id, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code work fine for me!

Comment: I believe this would only work if I deleted the post manually ( I tried it but the image is still there).

Comment: @DánielMozsár Yes this will only trigger if you delete post from admin and manually. This snippet working on my end . But you can use another hook instead of raw SQL query which will delete your product right after product get stock out. This will more safest way i think. If you interested then i can test and share that snippet.